# Positive definite Hessian matrix yielding a local minimum: detail clarification

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

[Text in question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dPrha.png)

The above link is a portion of a solution to problem 9.31 from Rudin's Principals of Mathematical Analysis.  I'm confused as to how the person who solved this jumped from his or her selection of $\delta$ directly led to the fact that the function has a local minimum at $a$.  Any clarification would be much appreciated.

Comment: $|x|^{-2}r(x)\to 0.$

Comment: They chose $\delta$ on the supposition that $A$ was positive definite (from where the existence of the value $c$ is derived).

Answer (score 1):

$\delta$ is the radius of the neighborhood of $a$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that $f(x)\ge f(a)$ when $x$ is in that neighborhood. Once you have the inequality in some neighborhood, you have a local minimum.